# How to pass ModelList(ArrayList) from Adapter to Activity

Tags: java, android

I have create A RecyclerView of Product List. To show All Varient of Product when I click on Weight it will be open an Dialog in which other RecyclerView open and Display the varient of the Product(Here I'm Done).
But the problem is that I want to set the Dialog data into Product List RecyclerView(From dialog to Activity) with the same position of that Product.

Comment: Post some code snippets and screenshots to better understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the interface callback and method to pass the list from adapter to activity, you just need to pass the callback reference in adapter class from activity and then you can call method from adapter using this callback reference